# Character strings are converted to date in .csv. Can't even be converted back in Excel (R)

Tags: r, excel, csv

I have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
a=data.frame(c("MARCH3","SEPT9","XYZ","ABC","NNN"),c(1,2,3,4,5))
> a
  c..MARCH3....SEPT9....XYZ....ABC....NNN.. c.1..2..3..4..5.
1                                    MARCH3                1
2                                     SEPT9                2
3                                       XYZ                3
4                                       ABC                4
5                                       NNN                5
```

Write into csv: `write.csv(a,"test.csv")`

I want everything to stay the way it is but `MARCH3` and `SEPT9` become 3-Mar and 9-Sep. I have tried everything in Excel: formatting by date, text, custom...none works. 3-Mar would be converted to 42066 and 9-Sep to 42256. In reality, `a` is a fairly large table so this can't even be done manually. Is there a way to coerce `a[,1]` so that Excel would ignore its format?

Comment: If you're getting the date numbers (42066 and 42256) then Excel has apparently recognized the incoming data as dates; it's just that it seems to be having a hard time formatting it properly for output. What does these values look like in the .csv file?

Comment: If the R CSV reader ignores whitespace in cells, then you can add a tab character at the start of each cell. Excel will then treat the cell as a string type and won't auto-convert to a date. Excel also doesn't display the tab character in the sheet, however you can see it in the formula bar.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to prevent Excel from autoformatting would probably be to store the data as excel file:

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(a, "test.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to change the file extension (e.g. make it ".txt" or ".dat" or something like that). When you open such a file in Excel the text import wizard will open. Specify that the file is delimited with commas, then make sure to change the appropriate column from "General" to "Text".

As an example: looking at the data in the question it appears that your CSV file might look like

```
,,,,MARCH3,,,,1
,,,,SEPT9,,,,2
,,,,XYZ,,,,3
,,,,ABC,,,,4
,,,,NNN,,,,5
```

If I save this file with a ".csv" extension and open it in Excel I get:

```
            3-Mar               1
            9-Sep               2
            XYZ                 3
            ABC                 4
            NNN                 5
```

with the date values changed as you noted. When I change the file extension to ".dat", making no other changes to the file, and open it in Excel I'm presented with the Text Import Wizard. I tell Excel that the file is "Delimited", choose "Comma" as the delimiter, and in the column with the "MARCH3" and "SEPT9" values I change the Column Data Type to "Text" (instead of "General"). After I clicked the Finish button on the wizard I got the following data in the spreadsheet:

```
            MARCH3              1
            SEPT9               2
            XYZ                 3
            ABC                 4
            NNN                 5
```

I tried putting the MARCH3 and SEPT9 values in double-quotes to see if that would convince Excel to treat these values as text but Excel still converted these cells to dates.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to append a semicolon to all the gene names.  The added character convinces excel that this column is text not a date.  You can find and replace the semicolon later is you want, but most programs - like perseus will allow you to ignore everything after the semicolon so its not always a problem...

df$Gene.name <- paste(df$Gene.name, ";", sep="")

I would be interested in anyone has a trick for doing this to just the Sept, March gene names though...